# Proper use of BatchNormalization when Fine-Tunning

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning, fine-tuning

I`m using keras and TF 2.0
I'm trying to implement ResNet50 pre-trained on ImageNet to a different problem (pneumonia binary classification) and I've found that there is some discussion online about how to properly set batch normalization layers to do Fine-Tunning.
My question is if I should freeze all the layers in the model, or skip batch normalization layers to do proper fine tuning.By this I mean, if `resnet` is the pre-trained model

```
resnet.trainable = False
```

or

```
for layer in resnet.layers:
    if not isinstance(layer, keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
      layer.trainable = False
    enter code here
```

I'm reaching 97% test accuracy but I think it should perform better in such a simple task. Which way of freezing should I use?